# Finding stack traces for recovered nil pointer dereference

Tags: go

This program produces an intentional nil pointer dereference. Most `error`s include stack traces and print the full trace when formatted as `%+v`. Nil pointer errors are `runtime.stringError`, which contains only a single field of type string

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime/debug"
)

func main() {
    defer func() {
        if x := recover(); x != nil {
            println(fmt.Sprintf("%T: %+v", x, x))
            debug.PrintStack()
        }
    }()
    var x *int
    *x = 1 // intentionally trigger a nil deref
}
```

This produces the following output (with no stack trace in the println):

```
runtime.errorString: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime/debug.Stack(0x10d0c88, 0x1, 0x1)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.16.2/libexec/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x9f
runtime/debug.PrintStack()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.16.2/libexec/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:16 +0x25
main.main.func1()
    /Users/me/go/src/github.com/me/project/main.go:12 +0xea
panic(0x10b3c40, 0x115ad60)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.16.2/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:965 +0x1b9
main.main()
    /Users/kyle/go/src/github.com/kyleu/admini/main.go:16 +0x41
```

The stack trace printed by `debug.PrintStack()` contains the line that PrintStack was called on, but no details about the error cause

Is it possible to get the stack trace of a `recover`ed runtime.errorString, like a nil pointer dereference?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Stack

Comment: An example of what Volker points to in his comment: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/860704317e02d699e4e4a24103853c4782d746c1/src/net/http/server.go#L1821-L1826

Comment: That prints the current stack, doesn't it? I'm looking for the full stack trace at the time of the exception. By the time debug.Stack runs, all the fun stack frames are gone

Comment: In case it helps anyone having a similar issue with go's http package, for me it ended up being http.TimeoutHandler eating stack frames: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27375

Answer (score 0):

I think it's quite easier with `debug.Stack()` from `runtime/debug`.

You can try this way:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "runtime/debug"
)

func main() {
    defer func() {
        if x := recover(); x != nil {
            println(fmt.Sprintf("%T: %+v", x, x))
            log.Printf("%s\n", debug.Stack())
        }
    }()
    var x *int
    *x = 1 // intentionally trigger a nil deref
}
```

You can't hardly ask for more as you already get the error message from `recover()` and the full list of functions to the line causing panic in the traces. That's why I recommend to use `debug.Stack()` because it returns the traces instead of printing out and you can apply some filter on it for more useful information.

Comment: That prints the current stack, doesn't it? I'm looking for the full stack trace at the time of  the exception. By the time `debug.Stack` runs, all the fun stack frames are gone

Comment: It's current stack actually. But as long as you call it at recover() of the same go-routine, it always tracks down to the line causing panic.

Comment: The exact location isn't present. When I add `debug.PrintStack()` in my recover func,
it prints a stack that contains a reference to the line calling `PrintStack`, but doesn't contain any information about the line with the dereference. This is a toy example, but sometimes the actual cause can be twenty frames deep before it's recovered

Comment: Can you update your question to elaborate the case it doesn't work?